# Is it possible to diy a command under Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash

For example, can I set?

```
gb = cd /media/Dan/evolution
```

so that everytime I execute gb in bash , I can cd to that particular directory?

I find something online, 'alias' command. But It seems can't do the work above.

Is it possible to do it? How?

# I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
alias gb='cd /media/Dan/evolution'
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file and everytime when you type `gb` your shell changes to the directory `/media/Dan/evolution`.

Running below command would add a line to `.bashrc` file

```
echo  "alias gb='cd /media/Dan/evolution'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

And then restart the terminal